# Multiple import ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have next situation - i'm using library material-ui;
And don't want each time use straight way to `node_modules` for importing required me component `'@material-ui/core/Tabs'`.
I decided to use `proxy-file` which import all component and then export them for use more comfortable use import MU componentns import - something line import Button from `'components/Button'`. I would love to use flexible import from array list. Example code:

```
<code>
const materialComponents = [
  Button
];

materialComponents.forEach(item=>{
  import item from `@material-ui/core/${item}`
});


export default {
  ...materialComponents
}
</code>
```

So...I have problem with `import item from @material-ui/core/${item}`
Compiler says that i need use string for route.

How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: es imports must be statically analyzable so you cannot do it like this. You can use dynamic imports or, if you use webpack there's some limited option for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your goal correctly, you can achieve the same thing without an additional file.

Either:

```
import { Button, Card, Icon } from '@material-ui/core'
```

And then use the components as usual, or use the 'import as' syntax to import all components under a common namespace, ie:

```
import * as components from '@material-ui/core'
```

You can then use the imported components by invoking `<components.Button>` etc.

Comment: Sounds good but there are one problem - routes to component are dynamic:
import { Button, Card, Icon } from '@material-ui' - doesn't work. I need make 3 different import:
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Card } from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import { Icon } from '@material-ui/core/Icon'

Comment: Why 3?

You can do it like

``import { Button, Card, Icon } from '@material-ui/core'``

Comment: You are right. Didn't notice that i can import from 'core/'directory. For some reason thought that components import from particular component file. Thanks a lot.